# how can i take a quality output of a gif file in photoshop?

Tags: gif

I am making a .gif file in Photoshop CS5. While saving this animation, I used the steps = File > Save for web & devices > Preset= GIF 128 No Dithered Bicubic> GIF > Save. After saving the .gif file the quality of the file is gone , i get the quality out put for the same file as .png and .jpg, please help it's urgent

Comment: Can you add screenshots? Do you know the difference between gif format and jpg format? What do you mean with "the quality is gone"?

Answer (score 1):

GIF can only use a palette of up to 255 colors. You ***can not get photo quality*** with GIF. It's just the way GIF was developed to send compressed images over the web back in the day when sending such data could be difficult and expensive.